# Having clause is not filtering records mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get `total sum of hours` for each `project_type` for a particular `year`, and hence a single row as a result.

Here's my SQL query:

```
select SUM(total_hours) as hours, year(task_completion) as year
from task_details
group by project_type_id
having year = '2018' AND project_type_id = 10
```

Also, here's how my data-set looks like:

```
project_type_id  |   total_hours   |  task_completion
-------------------------------------------------------
10               |   5             |  2018-9-10
10               |   4             |  2018-9-11
10               |   10            |  2017-9-10
10               |   2             |  2016-9-10
11               |   9             |  2017-9-10
14               |   8             |  2017-9-11
```

The query gives output as :

```
hours  |  year
---------------
21     |  2018
```

But I expected it to be `9`.

What is wrong with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query logic is simply off.  You have a `GROUP BY` use different unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.  You have columns in the `HAVING` that are neither aggregated nor in the `GROUP BY`.  MySQL extends its syntax to allow this.  However, the query (and results) do not make sense.

Your query should look like this:

```
select sum(total_hours) as hours, year(task_completion) as year
from task_details
where project_type_id = 10
group by year
having year = 2018;
```

What is the difference?  Note:

- The comparison for `project_type_id` is in the `WHERE` clause *before* aggregation, rather than after aggregation.
- The `GROUP BY` clause contains the unaggregated columns from the `SELECT`.
- `year` is a number, so the comparison is to a number, not a string.

I would advise you to do *all* the comparisons before the aggregation -- so no `having` clause is needed:

```
select sum(total_hours) as hours,
       year(task_completion) as year
from task_details
where project_type_id = 10 and
      task_completion >= '2018-01-01' and
      task_completion < '2019-01-01'
group by year;
```

Note this version does not use `year()`.  Functions on columns can impede the use of indexes.  This version can use an index on `(project_type_id, task_completion)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use condition for year and `project_type_id` in the `where` instead of `having`, otherwise it was summing values for all the year:

```
select project_type_id, 
       SUM(total_hours) as hours, 
       year(task_completion) as year_completion
from task_details
WHERE year(task_completion) = 2018 
 and project_type_id = 10
group by project_type_id
```